# How to turn off AutoLayout for a view hierarchy programmatically?

Tags: storyboard, autolayout, xib, nsview, nsscrollview

I have created a separate framework to house my view hierarchy that should *not* have AutoLayout enabled. To achieve this I have un-ticked the "Use Auto Layout" checkbox in Interface Builder (on storyboard).

I add the following action to a button within this basic view to test that no constraints have been generated on the view hierarchy (view + button):

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender:AnyObject?){
    println(self.view.constraints)
    println(self.view.subviews[0].constraints)
}
```

I then import the framework above into a new Cocoa Application which does have AutoLayout enabled and re-use the View Controller from the framework above within a container View Controller. When pushing the button, the following is the result:

```
[]
[<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6080000a7da0 H:
[NSButton:0x600000140e70'Button'(46)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>,
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6080000ad6e0
V:NSButton:0x600000140e70'Button'(21)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>]
```

## Questions:

1. does the above mean that my button has somehow picked up some constraints?
2. Is their another (more programmatic way) to turn off AutoLayout in a view hierarchy - in this instance, I don't use the storyboard for anything other than turning off constraints.

Further Info:

`translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints` is set to false for both the view and the button - to be safe.

I also have tried to run Instruments/AutoLayout but this crashes when my program starts up. The stack trace in the crash report shows that it is busy with AutoLayout related calls at the point of crash!

## EDIT

I am wanting to disable the use of AutoLayout in a part of my view hierarchy solely to gain performance benefits in scrolling a document with complex layout.

My scrollView is performing scrolling on a control akin to a tableView (it is a spreadsheet grid). My approach has been to move (aka relayout) cells from the left as you scroll right etc... What I find is that when I scroll really fast there is a lag-effect (which manifests as flashing/flickering in the corner of the screen) with the cells being unable to move across fast enough. They do of course catch up 500ms-1000ms or so later, but it doesn't look as good as it could.

Using Instruments (time profiler) I could also see that a large percentage of the busy time was taken by "layout & display" with layout being about even with display. I also performed tests without content being loaded into the cells to hone in on whether it was layout that was not happening fast enough (and it isn't).

More anecdotally, looking at Instruments (AutoLayout) I could certainly see that it was very busy attending to constraints during scrolling though I can't say whether this was necessarily bad.

My thinking is that with a complex (by number of moving parts) view/control like this one, AutoLayout may take longer to mathematically solve the constraint set problem than the time it would take if I directly tell it what the new frames are directly.

Comment: Have you tried putting your grid view (which doesn't use auto layout, itself, as I understand) into a window where nothing under your control is using auto layout either? Have you found any baseline scenario that gives acceptable performance to compare the auto layout case against? Are you taking advantage of Responsive Scrolling and keeping cells that fall within the view's `preparedContentRect` rather than just its `visibleRect`?

Comment: Initial implementation of grid was using AutoLayout. Spent most of today re-implementing without auto layout. It doesn't look like the non-autolayout way performs better AND I need auto-layout in the rest of the window - dead-end, u-turn, carry-on!

Comment: I do have some allowance for overdraw in my layout (couple of columns & rows - was trying to conserve memory) BUT it is not matched with `preparedContentRect` in any way. What I suspect might be happening is that AppKit is doing overdraw beyond my rudimentary overdraw and is therefore physically preparing some blank canvas to happily show me when I scroll - only afterwards does it attend to re-laying out those views.

Comment: @KenThomases Could you use a combination of `preparedContentRect` (to align your overdraw with AppKit expectations) and `adjustScroll` (to "somehow" slow it down when it tries to scroll beyond your overdraw)?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd arrange to slow down a scroll using `-adjustScroll:`. If your view can't or doesn't want to prepare as much content as AppKit wants for overdraw, override `-prepareContentInRect:` (not that same as `-preparedContentRect`). You can adjust the rect you pass through to `super` and that lets AppKit know how much you have actually prepared. If you pass through the same rect twice in a row, AppKit gets the message and stops trying to extend the overdraw region (until the user scrolls again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto layout is enabled or disabled per window, not for sections of a view hierarchy. If anything in the window uses auto layout, then the window as a whole does. That is, if anything adds or activates a constraint for any view in the window's hierarchy, or any view's class overrides `+requiresConstraintBasedLayout` to return true, then the window will use auto layout.

Note that system views and even the theme frame views (what draws the title bar) can use auto layout without you knowing it. Even if the views in your window aren't using auto layout in the current version of the OS, they could change to do so in any future version.

So: no, you can't disable auto layout for certain.

Setting `translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints` to false does not avoid turning on auto layout. It just means that if auto layout **is** turned on (by something else) those views will just be laid out incorrectly (since they are not getting constraints from anywhere else). Typically, setting `translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints` to false is only done by code that is opting **in** to auto layout.

`translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints` defaulting to true is what allows the system to transparently enable auto layout in windows in apps which were not designed to use auto layout without breaking their behavior.

How have you determined that auto layout is implicated in performance problems when scrolling?

---

Update:

A possible approach to alleviating any performance hit from auto layout for your grid view is to turn off `translatesAutoResizingMasksIntoConstraints` for the cell views as you had (and as I had said was a bad idea) and then manually set their frames in an override of `-layout`. I *think* that's legal.

You presumably would also set their frames when adding them to their superview, but that's not enough. Auto layout will likely zero their frames if you don't lay them out in your `-layout` override.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Can I clarify on it being enabled/diabled per Window OR per nib/storyboard - I have seen the latter mentioned on SO and hence my approach. I do want to use AutoLayout in the res of the window and was hoping to contain the "problem child" in a separate storyboard with AutoLayout disabled. (2) I have elaborated on your very relevant ending question by editing my original question.

Comment: When you're designing, you enable or disable auto layout for the NIB or the storyboard. For this purpose, it is not per window. A NIB could contain multiple windows or just a view hierarchy and no window, for example. However, at run time, auto layout is enabled or disabled for a window as I described. So, if you have a view NIB that doesn't use auto layout but you load it and add its view to a window that does, then the window is still using auto layout for everything within it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional suggestion.

Comment: Could you process the "non-autolayout" layout you mention above off the main thread? This could provide a further performance boost.

Comment: I doubt it. You should not manipulate the view hierarchy from a background thread. Even if it works, it would only be because Cocoa is synchronizing to the main thread under the hood, so you'd lose any advantage.